# Use of gettext in a Shiny application

Tags: r, shiny, gettext

I noticed a strange behaviour of `gettext` in a Shiny application running on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine.

From `?gettext`, we learn that:

> If domain is NULL or "", and gettext or ngettext is called from a function in the namespace of package **pkg** the domain is set to "R-pkg".

But when I develop a package using `gettext` to perform the internationalization in an associated Shiny app, messages are not always translated.

I have developed a small reproducible example that you can find at [Github](https://github.com/Tutuchan/gettext) :

```
devtools::install_github("tutuchan/gettext")
```

It is a very simple package with three functions:

- `hello()` calls `gettext("Hello, world!")`, **implicitly** specifying the domain as *R-gettext*,
- `hello2()` calls `gettext("Hello, world!", domain = "R-gettext")`, **explicitly** specifying the domain as *R-gettext*,
- `app()` is a wrapper around `shiny::runApp()` to launch the app directly

The package includes the .po file for a French translation (which requires you to have a "fr_FR.UTF8" locale on your system to try it out).

If I call `app()`, both strings are translated:

[image: app]

But if I run the app directly, either by opening the file and clicking the *Run App* button in RStudio or by calling `shiny::runApp("inst/app")`, only the message with the domain called explicitly is translated:

[image]

I may have misunderstood the help from `gettext` but I'd be glad if anyone could shed some light on this.

Does `gettext` consider the **top-level** calling function when trying to match the domain ? Because in that case, it would make sense that when calling `app()`, all messages are translated while when calling `shiny::runApp()`, only those with explicit domains are translated (because for implicit domains, `gettext` would look for .po files in the namespace of the **shiny** package). 
But I figured it would look for the domain of the function actually calling `gettext`.

Comment: In both case you have warnings : `LC_MESSAGES exists on Windows but is not operational` and `OS reports request to set locale to "fr_FR.utf8" cannot be honored`

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention that I'm on Ubuntu in the post, will edit that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `gettext` looks indeed in the namespace of the **toplevel function**  for translation files when the domain is not specified.

I created [another package](https://github.com/Tutuchan/gettextpo) that contains translation files and calls the app from my **gettext** package. When `gettextpo::app()` is called (which calls `gettext::app()` internally, the translation when the domain is implicit is found in the namespace of the **gettextpo** package, and not **gettext**.

[image]