# Multi language support for markdown, bookdown, quarto and dashboard in R

Tags: r, markdown, language-translation

When I create a website with `markdown`, `bookdown`, `blogdown` or `quarto` and `flexdashboards` what are my options when I like to make those sites multi-lingual (at least bi-lingual).

I am not looking for https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/internationalization.html in the sense that I write those in another language than English. I like to have a language switch option.

A similar question has been asked here [Multi-language support on R flexdashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61623771/multi-language-support-on-r-flexdashboard) for the dashboards, where https://appsilon.github.io/shiny.i18n/index.html seems to be one approach.

[image]

It requires to store all language version in parallel in a JSON file like this

[image]

Is there another API-solution where have automatic website translation from google or deepl and simply integrate a language bottom in my markdown?

Comment: The base-R `gettext` can be used for this if your rmarkdown is implemented in a package, where all you'd need to do is add a top-level `po/` directory. (https://stackoverflow.com/q/41382518/3358272 is related.)